# How to create a conditional dropdown menu using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a drop down list based on another drop down list's selection.
If `Brand Preference` or `Brand Purchased` is selected then the DIV `select_a_brand` should be appeared. I use following code. It hides the DIV `select_a_brand` but when I select an option `Brand Preference` or `Brand Purchased` still the DIV `select_a_brand` is hidden. It's not shown. How can I solve this?

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="form_controller required">By Brand</label>
    <select style="width: 218px;">
        <option>Select an option</option>
        <option id="brand_preference">Brand Preference</option>
        <option id="brand_purchased">Brand Purchased</option>
    </select>
    <div id="select_a_brand">   
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'brand_id', gGetBrandList('brand_id', 'brand_id, brand_name'), array('prompt'=>'Select a brand')); ?> 
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#select_a_brand').hide();                   

            jQuery('#brand_preference').select(function(){
                jQuery('#select_a_brand').show();    
            });             
        });
    </script>           
</div>
```

Comment: `.select()` is a handler for the event of selecting the contents of an element. You're looking for `.change()` instead.

Comment: thanks for that. but still it does nothing.. fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/riffaz/vyvjww79/2/

Comment: Remove the `PHP` bits from the question and replace them with the `HTML` markup generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use appropriate on change event handler of jquery; Plus you must bind to parent select box .  Ihave changed [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyvjww79/5/) and it is working well now:   Refer below code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#select_a_brand').hide();                   

    jQuery( "#base_option" ).change(function() {     


        if($(this).val() == "Brand Purchased" ){
           alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
        }
    });

});
```

select is not event its just api to select particular index/value of dropdown.

Comment: thanks for that. but still it does nothing.. fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/riffaz/vyvjww79/2/